# How to create new Row's without JPA consider it an update?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm working in a project right now, here is a piece of code:

```
public boolean getAll() {
        TypedQuery<Tag> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Tag c WHERE (c.tagName !=?1 AND c.tagName !=?2 AND c.tagName !=?3) ", Tag.class);
        query.setParameter(1, "Complete");
        query.setParameter(2, "GroupA");
        query.setParameter(3, "GroupB");

        List<Tag> Tag= query.getResultList();
```

But when I try to do something like this:

```
Tag.get(2).setTagName = "Hello";
em.persist(Tag.get(2));
```

It considers it to be an update instead of a create? How can I make JPA understand that it's not database related, to detach the chains with the Database and create new register only changing its name for example?

Thanks a lot for any help!
Best regards!

EDIT:

Using the `em.detach` just before changing it values and persisting each of the list worked just fine!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision whether to update or create a new entity object is done based on the primary key. You're probably using an ID on every object. Change or remove it and persist then. This should create a new entry.

If that doesn't work, you might need to detach the object from the Entity Manager first:

```
em.detach(tagObj);
```

and persist it afterwards:

```
em.persist(tagObj);
```

You can also force an update instead of creation by using

```
em.merge(tagObj)
```

There is no equivalent for forced creation AFAIK. `persist` will do both depending on PK.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't showed us how you are obtaining your list, but there are two key points here:

1. everything read in from an EntityManager is managed - JPA checks
   these managed objects for changes and will synchronize them with the
   database when required (either by committing the transaction or
   calling flush).
2. Calling persist on a managed entity is a no-op - the entity is
       already managed, and will be synchronized with the database if it
       isn't in there yet.

So the first Tag.get(2).setTagName = "Hello"; call is what causes your update, while the persist is a no-op.

What you need do to instead is create a new instance of your tag object and set the field. Create a clone method on your object that copies everything but the ID field, and then call persist on the result to get an insert for a new Entity.

Comment: I did this, but when I was setting it produced me the same mistake, only using em.detach right before helped in this case because my ID will need to be changed in my case.

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you said you 'did' that produced the same mistake.  You can only get the same mistake if you persist an entity that has the same primary key as an existing entity - I said to clone everything you need except the id.  Leave it blank to have the provider assign a new one, or set it to something that is unused.  Detach will remove the entity from the context, but may not work as you would expect if you try changing the ID and reassociate it to the persistence context, especially if you have other entities that reference it.

Comment: So, what I did was to create a new object like: new Tag, then maybe I made a mistake to do like this Tag_ =  Tag.get(1) for example. But I also tried to copy each value, like this Tag_.setAttribute(Tag.get(1).getAttribute()). And before em.detach() it doesn't worked as expected.

But obivously it could be my mistake in anything in my code.